# How do I change the navbar content when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's not just about changing specific CSS like background color, but actually show different content, or the same content but rearranged differently. I'm using Bootstrap.

I want to do what http://www.univision.com/noticias did.

Should I make a different navbar and with jQuery make it appear or disappear, depending if the user has scrolled? Do you guys know the code for this.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not css at all. It's just javascript

Answer (score 0):

This effect can be achieved using CSS and a little bit of JavaScript. You can add a JavaScript scroll eventlistener, check for the desired offsets and accordingly add or remove CSS classes from the html elements.

**Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="default-style">Hello World</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
.default-style {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.changed-style {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
function init() {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset;
    var breakpoint = 300; // you can change this value according to your layouts
    var elementToChange = $(".default-style");
    if (distanceY > breakpoint) {
        elementToChange.addClass("changed-style");
    }
    else {
        if (elementToChange.hasClass("default-style")) {
            elementToChange.removeClass("changed-style");
        }
    }
});
}

window.onload = init();
```

Of course, in your case you may want to change the bootstrap classes of the header (as you said you were using Bootstrap). E.g.

If you have three menus

```
<div class="col-md-4 menu-1">Home</div>
<div class="col-md-4 menu-2">About</div>
<div class="col-md-4 menu-3">Contact</div>
```

And let's say when user scrolls you want to hide **Menu 3** and divide the total browser width in half (for **Menu 1** and **Menu 2**). You could do:

```
function init() {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset;
    var breakpoint = 300; // you can change this value according to your layouts
    var menu1 = $(".menu-1"), menu2 = $(".menu-2"), menu3 = $(".menu-3");
    if (distanceY > breakpoint) {
        menu3.hide();
        menu1.addClass("col-md-6");
        menu2.addClass("col-md-6");
    }
    else {
        if (menu1.hasClass("col-md-6") || menu2.hasClass("col-md-6")) {
            menu1.removeClass("col-md-6");
            menu2.removeClass("col-md-6");
        }
    }
});
}

window.onload = init();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Aneeq, but what if I want for it to have different content all together? Like instead of saying Hello World, now it has a Hello World and different tabs: Menu 1 - Menu 2 - Menu 3?

Should I use classes to hide them and show them accordingly?

Comment: @Andrea Yeah you should use classes for stylizing the menus (bootstrap has built in classes as you said you were using it). You can just toggle those bootstrap classes using JS or jQuery based on scroll event. I have updated the answer as an example as well.